# SetAccessor functions not being called in C++ module for Node.js using NAN

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I'm trying to make a module in C++ for Node.js. I got the module set up and working, and Node.js sees the module no problem. It can be initialized and deinitialized and all of the code seems to be in working order. However, I am trying to declare getters and setters in C++ to be accessed in Node.js, but they aren't working as expected. I'm using NAN, so I'm trying to use this code as a guide: https://github.com/rvagg/nan/blob/master/test/cpp/settergetter.cpp

Below is the code. I'm fairly new to this, so I could definitely use a little help. Thank you much!

node_opus.cc:

```
namespace nodeopus {

    Persistent<Function> NodeOpus::constructor;

    NodeOpus::NodeOpus() :
    encoder( NULL ), // We have no encoder yet
    sampleRate( 48000 ), // Highest bitrate?
    channels( 2 ), // Stereo
    bitrate( 64000 ), // Default bitrate of 64k
    signal( OPUS_SIGNAL_MUSIC ), // Default of music
    application( OPUS_APPLICATION_AUDIO ) { // Encoding audio
        fprintf( stderr, "C constructor.\n" );
    }
    NodeOpus::~NodeOpus() {
        fprintf( stderr, "C destructor.\n" );
    }

    void NodeOpus::Init( Handle<Object> exports ) {
        NanScope();

        Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = NanNew<FunctionTemplate>( New );
        tpl->SetClassName( NanNew( "NodeOpus" ) );
        tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount( 1 );

        NanAssignPersistent( constructor, tpl->GetFunction() );

        v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> proto = tpl->PrototypeTemplate();
        proto->SetAccessor( NanNew<v8::String>( "samplerate" ),
                NodeOpus::SampleRateGetter,
                NodeOpus::SampleRateSetter );

        exports->Set( NanNew( "NodeOpus" ), tpl->GetFunction() );

        fprintf( stderr, "Init called.\n" );
    }

    NAN_METHOD( NodeOpus::New ) {
        NanScope();

        if( args.IsConstructCall() ) {

            NodeOpus *obj = new NodeOpus();
            obj->Wrap( args.This() );
            NanReturnValue( args.This() );

            fprintf( stderr, "New constructor called.\n" );
        }
        else {
            const int argc = 0;
            Local<Value> argv[ argc ] = {};
            Local<Function> cons = NanNew<Function>( constructor );
            NanReturnValue( cons->NewInstance( argc, argv ) );

            fprintf( stderr, "New not constructor called.\n" );
        }
    }

    NAN_GETTER( NodeOpus::SampleRateGetter ) {
        NanScope();

        NodeOpus *obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<NodeOpus>( args.This() );

        NanReturnValue( NanNew<Int32>( obj->sampleRate ) );
    }

    NAN_SETTER( NodeOpus::SampleRateSetter ) {
        NanScope();

        NodeOpus *obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<NodeOpus>( args.This() );

        if( !value->IsInt32() ) {
            NanThrowError( "Sample Rate must be an integer." );
            return;
        }

        obj->sampleRate = value->Int32Value();

        fprintf( stderr, "Value is %i\n", obj->sampleRate );

    }
}
```

node-opus.js:

```
var binding = require( 'bindings' )( 'nodeopus' );

var nopus = new binding.NodeOpus();

nopus.samplerate = 32;
console.log( nopus.samplerate );
```

The output:

```
node node-opus.js 
Init called.
C constructor.
32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the constructor variable to:

```
Persistent<FunctionTemplate> NodeOpus::constructor;
```

And the Init function to:

```
void NodeOpus::Init( Handle<Object> exports ) {
    NanScope();

    Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = NanNew<FunctionTemplate>( New );

    NanAssignPersistent( constructor, tpl );

    tpl->SetClassName( NanNew( "NodeOpus" ) );

    tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount( 1 );

    Local<ObjectTemplate> proto = tpl->PrototypeTemplate();

    proto->SetAccessor( NanNew( "samplerate" ),
            SampleRateGetter,
            SampleRateSetter );

    exports->Set( NanNew( "NodeOpus" ), tpl->GetFunction() );

    fprintf( stdout, "Init called.\n" );
}
```

Now setting the samplerate to a value will trigger the functions in C++. I'm not sure why using a FunctionTemplate instead a Function variable works, but I'm just glad it's working.